# horizontally center logo & li elements

Tags: html, css, nav

I need to align the logo and links horizontally in my navigation. Can you spot where I am going wrong or what I am missing?!

The text links appear to be on the bottom and I'd like to have them move up but unable to achieve this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Please help.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li class="logo"><img src="images/danielmaldonado_logo.svg" width="100px"></li>
    <li>RESUME</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin:auto;
    line-height:100px;
}


li.logo{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:10px;
}

nav li{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;

}

li{
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: montserrat;
    font-weight:thin;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    margin: 0 15px; 0 0;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `vertical-align : middle` for image.

```
li.logo img{
   vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by using `vertical-align:middle;` property set into `<li>` element.

check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DkvLF/)</kbd>

#### CSS

```
nav li{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;      // <--- Add this in property
}
```

---

I am change font color #FFF to #000 in jsFiddle demo. So you can recharge on your self. 
Hope this help you!